# Javafx Tabpane's size always one and the other tabs are always null

Tags: java, javafx

When the scene is first opened, tabpane only sees one of the tab which is opened by default. In other words, tabpane.getTabs().size() always equals 1. And Also all of the tabs are null.

```
public TabPane tabpane;
public Tab sellScreenTab;
public Tab buyScreenTab;
public Tab stockControlTab;
public Tab logTab;
public Tab userTab;
public Tab statisticsTab;


public void editTabsForUsers(){
    System.out.println(tabpane.getTabs().size());
    if (!Session.user.sellScreenPerm){
        sellScreenTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(sellScreenTab);
    }if (!Session.user.entryScreenPerm){
        buyScreenTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(buyScreenTab);
    }if (!Session.user.historyScreenPerm){
        logTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(logTab);
    }if (!Session.user.statsScreenPerm){
        statisticsTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(statisticsTab);
    }if (!Session.user.trackStockScreenPerm){
        stockControlTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(stockControlTab);
    }if (!Session.user.usersScreenPerm){
        userTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(userTab);
    }
}
```

In this part code prints, 1 and also this is the exception

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TabPane.getTabs()" because the return value of "javafx.scene.control.Tab.getTabPane()" is null

All of the tabs and tabpane defined on fxml

EDİT : İn app if I changed selected tab it will work correctly but I need to do before chage

Comment: Just assign it an initial value by defining a constructor.

Comment: [mcve] please.. mind the __M__

Comment: @mufazmi "Just assign it an initial value by defining a constructor." -> No.  If something was supposed to be defined in FXML, it should never be set to a new value in Java code.

Comment: Probably the `fx:id` values for the tab don't match your code references, so the FXML injection on them fails, but that is just speculation without the FXML source.